# NodeJS - Testing an API With Request And Promise

Tags: node.js, testing, request, es6-promise

I'm not an Javascript expert, and I failed to understand how to work some Js particularity.

I wanted to automated test, I dit it, it works.
The algorithm is simple :

*[for each] test [do] request() [then] testRequest().*

```
function requestFunction(url, KeyWord, path, expected){

    request( url + path + '/', function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == expected) {
        msgSuccess("["+KeyWord + "] :\t\tok\t(" + expected + ')' );
    }else{
        msgError("["+KeyWord + "]\t\tERROR => " + error);
        msgError("Error result: \n" + body);
    }
});
```

But **I want to split the test part, from the request, and manage it with promise**:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(requestFunction(url, KeyWord, path, expected));
var promise2 = new Promise(testRequest(error, response, body, expected));

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(
    console.log(KeyWord + " ok"),
    showOnlyTheError(allErrors));
```

But I have no idea how to **get and give the testRequestResult() parameters** (error, response, body)

The other point is that I'm pretty sure that **all the reject will be concatenated** and the **result will automatically goes to the allErrors variable**.

```
eg: testRequest(...){ reject("[Error]" + **ErrorNumbers** + ", ")};
```

Will at the end show **"1, 2, 3,"**.

But I can't explain why, and especially how?

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT] I TRIED THIS :**

```
var arrayOfPaths= [
'Ping',
'PING'];

var promises = arrayOfPaths.forEach(function(path){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        msgStatus(url+path+'/');
        return resolve(request(url+path+'/'));
    });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(
    function(result){
        //after all promises resolve do something with array of results
        msgStatus("result " + result.body );
    }
).catch(function(result){
        //if any of the promises fail they will be handled here
        //do something with errors
        msgError("err " + result.error );

    }
);
```

**=> But it is always gone in the catch part with this error:**

**err undefined**

My server received a good request and sent back a normal response (statusCode = 200)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to separate the test from the request.

If you had 10 tests that did api calls you would need to do `Promise.all([request1,request2,...])`. because the api calls are async and will resolve the promises at different times.

I would suggest using thens to wait for the response to resolve the promise it might look like this:

```
new Promise(function(resolve){
    request( url + path + '/', function (error, response, body) {
        return resolve({error:error,response:response,body:body})
    }
}.then(function(result){
    if (!result.error && result.response.statusCode == expected) {
        msgSuccess("["+KeyWord + "] :\t\tok\t(" + expected + ')' );
    }else{
        msgError("["+KeyWord + "]\t\tERROR => " + error);
        msgError("Error result: \n" + result.body);
    }
})
```

The multiple request looks like this

```
var promises = arrayOfUrlPaths.foreach(url){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
         return resolve(request(url))
    }
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(result){
    //after all promises resolve do something with array of results
}.catch(function(result){
    //if any of the promises fail they will be handled here
    //do something with errors
})
```

)

Comment: Sorry to answer just now, I have some issue with internet at home. I have some issue with your solution (I rectified syntaxes error), it always going into the catch part with this error => TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined But my server receive a good request and send a normal response..  
-Look at my edit